# Redefining CJKfamily warning

Tags: ctex

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 1}
    \begin{center}
        赴戍登程口占示家人二首（其二）
        \medskip

        \fangsong{【清】林则徐}
        \bigskip

        \kaishu{
        力微任重久神疲，再竭衰庸定不支。

        苟利国家生死以，岂因祸福避趋之！

        谪居正是君恩厚，养拙刚于戍卒宜。

        戏与山妻谈故事，试吟断送老头皮。
        }
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

If I write `\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}`, it will say:
**Error: Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}**

If I write `\usepackage[fontset=windows]{ctex}`, it will say:
**Warning: Redefining CJKfamily `\CJKrmdefault' (SimSun(0)).**

What should I do? Can someone teach me how to write a fontset myself?

I prefers to use the `\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}` so I can use my own fontset but it returns error.

Answer (score 1):

- You need `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`
- If you use it `\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}`, you will not be able to use commands such as `\fangsong`, so there's the `Undefined control sequence`

If you want to use commands like `\fangsong`, please refer to `texdoc ctex` to set the font command, or ignore the warning